# Equivalent of theme_set for scale_color/scale_fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a small Corporate Design package for ggplot visualizations and was wondering if there was an equivalent of theme_set() for scale_color and scale_fill. Thus instead of the standard palette functions a custom continuous or discrete palette in CD-colors is choosen.

Otherwise: Is there a good entry point to overwrite a function of ggplot2 from an external package to provide this function? I came up with ggplot() function like:

```r
cd_ggplot_continuous <- function(...) {
  ggplot(...) +
    cd_scale_color_continuous(...) +
    cd_scale_fill_continuous(...)
}
```

and

```r
cd_ggplot_discrete <- function(...) {
   ggplot(...) +
     cd_scale_color_discrete(...) +
     cd_scale_fill_discrete(...)
}
```

Though I am not a big fan of such a solution.

Comment: I would define a custom theme (function or constant) for your organization so that users can do like `ggplot(...) + ... + ... + our_theme()`.  Would this fit your need?

Comment: It's not about setting a theme, it's about setting a color/fill scheme. Thus this function would first need to check whether a discrete/continuous color of fill palette is needed. And this would be the step I am not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default scale object in `options`.

Here is a vanilla ggplot:

```r
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()

p
```

[image]

We set a default color palette like this:

```
options(ggplot2.discrete.colour = c("purple2", "blue3", "red4"))
```

So drawing any plot that uses a discrete color scale (unless otherwise specified) will use this palette.

```
p
```

[image]

Comment: Though it would not fit all criteria of a fairly complex color scheme convention: "it's something". Thank you! It should work for 90% of all cases.

Comment: @pteridin yes, it's just an example. It can easily be expanded. If you give an example of the actual colour schemes you wish to employ, I can demonstrate a full solution.

Comment: Ah perfect. It is possible to incorporate a color generating function. I would like to thank you for the offer of implementation though I would rather like to do it myself. It just clings better in my head when I do it on my own. Thank you!